# All Letters Upper-Case when Typing in DOSBox?

Tags: keyboard, dosbox

I am having to use DOSBox to run a old DOS-based program, but whenever I type a letter it's upper-case, rather than lower-case. The only way I can get a lower-case letter is by holding down shift. 
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Is this happening with other applications as well?

Comment: No, only with DOSBox. Could it be a keyboard mapping problem? Also, the CapsLock key doesn't seem to work...

Comment: The behaviour *appears* to be the same as when the Caps Lock key is pressed. So is there an option within DOSBox that affects this?

Comment: There appears to be issues around Caps Lock - http://vogons.zetafleet.com/viewtopic.php?t=25341&sid=62861b36aff4407763840bfb9c879195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, sorted out the problem: I went into DOSBox's keyboard mapping (Ctrl-F1) and set the "CAPS LOCK" Key to be always down ("Hold"). Everything now works as expected.